# sequential case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a little stuck on a project and wondering what you all would try next. I'm trying to create SQL code that will output the values in the `change_value` field of the below sample table.

```
id | sequence | event_type | change_value
 1 |     1    |      a     |       0
 1 |     2    |      b     |       1
 1 |     3    |      a     |       1
 1 |     4    |      b     |       1
 2 |     1    |      a     |       0
 2 |     2    |      b     |       1
 2 |     3    |      b     |       0
 2 |     4    |      b     |       0
 3 |     1    |      a     |       0
 3 |     2    |      a     |       0
 3 |     3    |      a     |       0
 3 |     4    |      a     |       0
```

For each row, the value will only be 0 or 1. The logic is as follows:

```
IF `id` in the current row = `id` in the previous row;
AND `sequence` in the current row > `sequence` in the previous row;
AND `event_type` in the current row <> `event_type` in the previous row;
THEN 1
ELSE 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with `left join`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when tprev.event_type is null then 0
             when tprev.event_type = t.event_type then 0
             else 1
        end) as change_value
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.id = t.id and
        tprev.sequence = t.sequence - 1;
```

This will work as long as the sequence numbers have no gaps.

There are basically two other approaches.  One method is a complicated query (say, a correlated subquery) to get the previous results.  The other is to use variables (another form of complicated query).  The above is simpler than these.  More importantly, it can take advantage of an index on `(id, sequence, event_type)` for performance.

Comment: i think OP mean `when tprev.event_type != t.event_type then 1`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This is a great solution to this problem!